# Application so slow to start from DVD

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with a large database (about 3.5 GB) that I need to run it from a read only file system like DVD. So my program works well from a hard disk but it's so slow to start from a DVD.

My question is how do I optimize my program to run fast on a DVD?

Comment: Do you catch and ignore exceptions during load?

Comment: A DVD (or other optical drive) is inherently slow media compared to a fixed hard drive, or even most USB drives.  Further, if you're running a read-only database then you won't be able to do much becaeuse it's third-party code that's handling your file access for that data.  Are you sure you really have to run from DVD?  Could you run from a read-only folder on a hard disk, for example?

Comment: Exactly my application is a learning package and i need to Run it form DVD.

Comment: You'll have to profile your application, there is no silver bullet that makes your app load three times as fast. Analyze, profile, see what data is causing the latency. Why is a _"learning package"_ 3.5 GB large? Do you store binary data (images, audio, video) in the database? Depending on the systems used, your application might require large portions of the database to be loaded into RAM which simply takes time since DVD is pretty slow medium. Is installing the application to the harddisk an option?

Comment: currently installing the application to the hard disk is not an option.i don't store binary data in database,they are in a separate file,(sorry)my data base is about 1 gb(string data) and i split my data base to some part.

Comment: Databases rely heavily on random access which is awfully slow on DVDs (even more so than on hard drives). Unless you find a way of packing the data you need at a time in contiguous chunks this will always be your main performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to profile your application, there is no silver bullet that makes your app load three times as fast. Analyze, profile, see what data is causing the latency

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on what kind of database you mean. I'll assume it's row based.

If you wish to make a database fast to read from, the first step is probably to sort the database. This is critical because it makes it possible to hunt down specific rows very quickly using a binary search.

Loading 3.5 Gb into ram to search through from a DVD is going to take as nearly as long as ripping a DVD, so that's why your program's going to be slow to start. Consider making an index that points to the locations of certain rows, like page numbers for the start of each letter in a dictionary. Then, you only need to load small portions of your database to find the rows you need. Then, slowly build up the dictionary in RAM by loading portions in the order of requirements (i.e, if you search for something, load that portion first).

Specifically to DVD, there's not much you can do to make it load faster. Consider a streaming compression type (GZip maybe, C# supports this natively) to allow you to pull data faster.

Again, it depends entirely on what you're doing, these are just general suggestions.

Comment: exactly i splited my data base to some part and when i need a part of data i will load it's data base part into ram,

Comment: So where is the bottleneck then? What takes a long time?